# XSLT - create recursive child emements using common element names

Tags: xslt, element, nested, renaming

I am new to XSLT and wonder if there is a solution to a requirement to put emements into recursivce parent/child elements

The XML I want to produce:

```
<NAVs>
 <NAV>
   <ShareClass1>A-USD</ShareClass1>
 </NAV>
 <NAV>
   <ShareClass1>A-SGD</ShareClass1>
</NAV>
<NAV>
   <ShareClass1>A-SGD (H)</ShareClass1>
</NAV>
</NAVs>
```

The XML I have.

```
<Share_class2_SH_1_NAV_lang_ID>A-USD</Share_class2_SH_1_NAV_lang_ID>
<Share_class2_SH_2_NAV_lang_ID>A-SGD</Share_class2_SH_2_NAV_lang_ID>
<Share_class2_SH_3_NAV_lang_ID>A-SGD (H)</Share_class2_SH_3_NAV_lang_ID>
<Share_class2_SH_4_NAV_lang_ID>A-ACC-AUD (H)</Share_class2_SH_4_NAV_lang_ID>
```

Any ideas as to how an XSLT template would be laid out?

Comment: Your input XML does not map to your wanted output XML. Compare share class. Also what happened to `<Share_class2_SH_4_NAV_lang_ID>`? Also, in what way is that recursive?

Comment: You have not answered my comment. Please don't make us guess how the input XML maps to the output XML. That's wasting everybody's time. Add a thorough explanation instead.

Comment: I have update my initial request and XML out will map. My aim is to create parent/child elements from the existing XML

Comment: As it currently stands your question is ambiguous to an outsider. It's absolutely unclear what goes where and why things have this name and where the `<NAV>` grouping comes from.

Comment: @GraemeMackay I have rolled your question back to its original form.  This question already has an answer, and the answer wouldn't make any sense without the original question. If you have further - or, as it seems, completely different - requirements, please open up a new question.

Comment: Michael - ok i am new to this - could you point me to the link where you state the answer to my question is

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing(!) you want something like the stylesheet shown below. However, first you'll need a **well-formed XML input** - one that has a *root element*, for example:

```
<input>
    <Share_class2_SH_1_NAV_lang_ID>A-USD</Share_class2_SH_1_NAV_lang_ID>
    <Share_class2_SH_2_NAV_lang_ID>A-SGD</Share_class2_SH_2_NAV_lang_ID>
    <Share_class2_SH_3_NAV_lang_ID>A-SGD (H)</Share_class2_SH_3_NAV_lang_ID>
    <Share_class2_SH_4_NAV_lang_ID>A-ACC-AUD (H)</Share_class2_SH_4_NAV_lang_ID>
</input>
```

Applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <NAVs>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
             <NAV>
                <ShareClass1><xsl:value-of select="."/></ShareClass1>
             </NAV>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </NAVs>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NAVs>
   <NAV>
      <ShareClass1>A-USD</ShareClass1>
   </NAV>
   <NAV>
      <ShareClass1>A-SGD</ShareClass1>
   </NAV>
   <NAV>
      <ShareClass1>A-SGD (H)</ShareClass1>
   </NAV>
   <NAV>
      <ShareClass1>A-ACC-AUD (H)</ShareClass1>
   </NAV>
</NAVs>
```

which may or may not be the result you're looking for.

Comment: Hello - thanks @michael.hor257k for the response and the full XML (well formed) tomorrow - I also have further elements I wish to include into the <NAV> child elements